# Angular 4 app slowing to a halt whenever a network call is made in IE

Tags: javascript, angular, http, internet-explorer, asp.net-web-api

I have an app that makes calls and then updates the screen based on the data coming in. The app is wicked slow on I.E (cant even scroll) but on Chrome the app is very fast. I noticed that if i stop all network calls then the app is also fast on IE. I thought maybe there was too much data on the screen being updated, so i had the Angular controllers stop updating the objects used on the screen; this did not help at all. So then I thought the amount of data on the get-request must be too large; so I changed the ASP.net-WebAPI to have small get requests that would check for an update flag and only request the full array of data if a change was made (this made the total data sent much smaller); these more frequent request with less than a kilobyte each made the app even less responsive!!! So are these "frequent" get-requests (only a few hundred bytes and once every 3 seconds) are way too much for IE to handle? This seems stupid; what is the real reason IE cannot handle my application? Are 20 get-requests/minute each of only a few hundred bytes really killing my app??? I know the renderer in IE is old, but why would my app freeze whenever a network call is made?!

I am using ng-bootstrap in my application. I also am using font-awesome, but taking out font awesome did not help.

Comment: IE has the fastest screen redraw in the market exceeding 120fps of JavaScript DOM animations on kiosk mode of full HD resolution screens. There is never too "much data"on the screen for IE. However,  using synchronous requests over the network for your data hungry application is a deliberate blocker. Your salad of plugin apis are forcing IE to halt all executions until the requested data become available. 80% of apis in circulation are not IE friendly another 20% of them are openly hostile.

Comment: @BekimBacaj thank you for your insight. If IE is faster, would you educate me on why chrome and firefox run perfectly responsive while these network calls are made? And my calls are actually all asynchronous from what I understand (promises and observables).

Comment: because the apis, you rely on doing your work, are deliberately written to clobber and whenever possible choke IE.

Comment: Angular and bootstrap? do you have any proof of this or explanation on how this works? I mean this question with respect in order so I can learn, not as a challenge.

Comment: well you need to be able to write your applications in vanilla JavaScript in order to understand how these tricks work. For instance the oldest one from the days o Netscape was to add a closing tag of an element that was never opened. As these things require a deep understanding of how things work you would never understand how does it cause additional lag at rendering of the document on IE alone, but does not affect others?

Comment: Hmmm. That's seems a bit handwavy. I'll keep looking for a more concrete reason as to why the app is slower in IE. It sounds like neither of us understand why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns a solution to making it run faster is to call enableProdMode(); in the main.ts

Strange that IE was so drastically effected by it while the other browsers were not. Makes it impossible for me to debug that component in IE though...